# Java multithread for nfc scanner

Tags: java, multithreading, nfc

i have startet to look at java for creating an java application for my nfc scanner

So far i am able to scan and read uid for tags when i press a button. (It locks my gui untill a tag is found)

I need the scanner to be scanning all the time when i press the button without locking my gui, and then update my gui when it finds a new tag

how ever i have never tried multithreading before so i dont know how to make my new thread to tell the other when it have found a new tag, how can i  do this?

NFC reader class

```
public class NFCCardReader {
    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    private List<CardTerminal> terminals;

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    protected NFCCardReader() {
        TerminalFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = TerminalFactory.getInstance("PC/SC", null);
            System.out.println(factory);
            terminals = factory.terminals().list();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CardException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected String scan() {
        if (terminals.isEmpty()) {
            return "Ingen NFC terminaler tilgængelig";
        }
        CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
        boolean looking = true;
        String uid = "";
        while (looking) {
            try {
                terminal.waitForCardPresent(0);
                Card card = terminal.connect("*");
                CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

                CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF,
                        (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04 });
                ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);

                byte[] byteArray = response.getBytes();
                uid = bytesToHex(byteArray);
                looking = false;
            } catch (CardException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return uid;
    }
}
```

controller class

```
private MainGui gui;
private Program program;

public Controller(MainGui gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    program = new Program();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == gui.btnScan) {
        gui.btnScan.setText("Scanning...");
        gui.lblUID.setText("Tag UID: " + program.nfcScan());
        gui.txaText.setText(program.getTagText());
    } else if (e.getSource() == gui.btnSave) {
        program.setTag(gui.txaText.getText());
    }
}
```

program class

```
public class Program {


    private Db db;
    private String currentUID = "", currentText = "";
    private NFCCardReader nfc;

    public Program() {
        db = new Db();
        nfc = new NFCCardReader();
    }

    public String nfcScan() {
        currentUID = nfc.scan();
        currentText = db.getTag(currentUID);
        return currentUID;
    }

    public String getTagText() {
        return currentText;
    }

    public void setTag(String text) {
        db.setTag(currentUID, text);
        currentText = text;
    }
}
```

MainGui class

```
public class MainGui extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6698282232100136737L;
    private Controller controller = new Controller(this);
    private JFrame prg;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    private Date date;
    private String formattedDate;
    protected JLabel lblUID;
    protected JButton btnScan, btnSave;
    protected JTextArea txaText;

    public MainGui(JFrame prg) {
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\tStarting program...");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.prg = prg;
        initialize();
    }

    public void closeProgram() {
        prg.dispose();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // initialize SETUP
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\tInitializing...");
        // initialize txaTEXT
        lblUID = new JLabel();
        lblUID.setText("Tag UID: ");
        lblUID.setSize(160, 30);
        lblUID.setLocation(30, 30);
        lblUID.setVisible(true);
        this.add(lblUID);
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\t\tlblUID been initialized at: "
                + lblUID.getX() + "," + lblUID.getY() + "\tSize: "
                + lblUID.getWidth() + "," + lblUID.getHeight());
        txaText = new JTextArea();
        txaText.setSize(370, 300);
        txaText.setLineWrap(true);
        txaText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txaText.setDragEnabled(false);
        txaText.setLocation(30, 70);
        txaText.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        txaText.setVisible(true);
        this.add(txaText);
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\t\ttxaText been initialized at: "
                + txaText.getX() + "," + txaText.getY() + "\tSize: "
                + txaText.getWidth() + "," + txaText.getHeight());
        btnScan = new JButton();
        btnScan.setText("Scan");
        btnScan.setLocation(330, 30);
        btnScan.setSize(70, 30);
        btnScan.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
        this.add(btnScan);
        btnScan.addActionListener(controller);
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\t\tbtnScan been initialized at: "
                + btnScan.getX() + "," + btnScan.getY() + "\tSize: "
                + btnScan.getWidth() + "," + btnScan.getHeight());
        btnSave = new JButton();
        btnSave.setText("Gem");
        btnSave.setLocation(330, 380);
        btnSave.setSize(70, 30);
        btnSave.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
        btnSave.addActionListener(controller);
        this.add(btnSave);
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\t\tbtnSave been initialized at: "
                + btnSave.getX() + "," + btnSave.getY() + "\tSize: "
                + btnSave.getWidth() + "," + btnSave.getHeight());
        date = new Date();
        formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "\tInitializing...COMPLETE");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need formulate your question more precisely. I miss following information:

0/ What is the 'other' Thread you need to communicate your barcode to? The UI thread? If yes, what UI you plan to use? Swing?

1/ Do you plan to read new barcodes in a loop? This is what you say but currently your while loop reads only one barcode and then it ends. Or are you looking for a way to read one bar code at time and only not block the UI?

Comment: @Michal Sorry about that, i tried to make it a bit more clear about what i want it to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/Please let your barcode reader class implement Runnable.

2/Start the background thread with the aforementioned Runnable for example 
via Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(...). Or as the other answer suggested.

3/Your UI is Swing. From inside the barcode reader you need to trigger functionality 
which updates the UI for each read barcode per SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). To test, you might simply put the SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) into bar code reader. For real-live solution you probably want to put this logic into the controller, perhaps having bar code reader firing an action. Important is, bar code reader triggers, but the triggered code is inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...).

You will also need provide for orderly shutdown of the application.  This might for example 
be done by making the looking variable volatile and exposing it per setter to the outside (UI, controller) code. UI/Controller might then use the setter to signalise the background thread it's time to stop reading the barcodes.

On the Swing Tutorial are examples and explanations regarding these kind of programming problems.

Comment: My comment about shutting down the application has one problem - the check for the looking variable comes first after a barcode has been read. So it might happen that after setting looking=false stiill one barcode has to be read first. Unfortunately, there is no clean way of handling this. It would help if the waitForCardPresent(..) would accept a timeout. Otherwise you just might happen to have to do System.exit(..) which is not clean way of ending the application.

Comment: Thanks much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class for running the thread. Then call the `.start` method of thread from where you want to run the thread.

```
package test;

public class MultiThreadApp {
    BackgroundThread bt = new BackgroundThread();

    public MultiThreadApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        bt.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultiThreadApp();
    }

    private class BackgroundThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("BackgroundThreadRunning");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's only the easy part. He is looking for way to pass information around.

Comment: How would i then make it send the tag it finds to my main thread?